# command substitution but without breaking output into multiple arguments

Tags: bash, shell, command, clipboard, substitution

Is there a way to do command substitution in BASH shell without breaking output into multiple arguments?

I copy the path of some directory (from the location bar in a GUI file browser) to clipboard and then issue the following command, where the command xsel returns the clipboard content, which is the path of the directory in this case:

```
cd `xsel`
```

But some path contain spaces or may even contain some special characters used by BASH.

How can I pass the output of a command as a single argument and without BASH messing with special characters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
cd "$(xsel)"
```

seems to handle all special characters (including $ and spaces).

My test string was `boo*;cd.*($\: $_`

```
$ mkdir "$(xsel)"
$ ls
boo*;cd.*($\: $_

$ file boo\*\;cd.\*\(\$\\\:\ \$_/
boo*;cd.*($\: $_/: directory

$ cd "$(xsel)"
$ pwd
/tmp/boo*;cd.*($\: $_
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
cd "`xsel`"
```

That should do the job, unless you have dollars($) or back-slashes (\) in your path.

Comment: I don't think it matters whether you have meta-characters in the string once you've wrapped the `xsel` in double-quotes

Comment: Bash will interpret a very small number of meta-characters inside double-quotes. Only single quotes stop all interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't doing this programmatically, *most* terminals in Linux let you paste from the clipboard with a middle-click on your mouse.  Of course, you'll still need to put quotes before and after your paste, like @dave suggests.

Comment: If the directory is
/egg/spam/chunky bacon/my music

and if I type cd and paste the path, it's

cd /egg/spam/chunky bacon/my music

, which will cd into /egg/spam/chunky.